# Busy indicator not showing in Jquery Dialog

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a jquery confirmation dialog.  When the user presses OK I execute an Ajax call that will take a few seconds.  During this delay I want to display on the dialog a gif animation so the user knows we are processing their data.  However, I cannot seem to get the gif to appear in the dialog.

The html is :

```
<div id="dlgReleaseConfirmation" title="ConfirmRelease" style="display : none"  >
    <div id="release-in-progress" style="display:none">
            <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" ></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code in the js file is:

```
       $("#dlgReleaseConfirmation").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Release": function () {
                $("#release-in-progress").show();       // show the busy div - not working, blocked by dialog?
                Release();   // release assays
                loadTable();           // refresh datatable
                $("#release-in-progress").hide();       // hide the busy div
                $(this).dialog("close");    // close this dialog
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Update with solution.

Alexander sent me down the correct road.  The bottom line is that you have to do the Ajax calls async so the dialog is updated to show the busy indicator.  But, if just do this then the issue becomes that the code will continue and close the screen while the ajax calls proceed async thus providing the user no feedback.

To fix this I added calls to ajaxStart() and ajaxStop() to hide and show the busy indicator while the async Ajax calls where proceeding.  Here is the release button handler code that works:

```
"Release": function () {
    $(this).ajaxStart(function () {
        $("#release-in-progress").show();   
    });
    $(this).ajaxStop(function () {
        $("#release-in-progress").hide();
        $(this).dialog("close");    // close this dialog
    });
    Release();   // release assays
    loadTable();           // refresh datatable
 };
```

Comment: Show us your CSS - chances are its appearing but you just cant see it as its appearing behind the dialog

Comment: If `loadTable()` is asynchronous you need to move the `$().hide()` to the complete callback. What is doing `loadTable()`?

Comment: where is your button in the given code?/

Comment: I am pretty sure the CSS is OK.  If I remove the "display : none" it shows all the time.

Comment: comment out your hide() and see if it displays when you hit your button

Comment: Regarding the button, this is a jquery-ui-dialog.  The button is added by that code, http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Comment: Alexander.  Load table is a .Ajax call with async : false.

Comment: @JerryKur, setting `async:false` may freeze the execution until the request is done and the resource is not being loaded. You need to use an asynchronous call

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I will try switching to async and see if there is a change.

Comment: @JerryKur, since it was as I expected, there I put it as an answer and don't forget to mark it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By executing a synchronous AJAX call (`async: false`) in the `loadTable()` function you are freezing the execution until the request is completed and the image resource is not being loaded. You need to use an asynchronous call to achieve what you want.

Comment: The goal is leave the dialog up with the busy gif being displayed until the data has been updated and the table updated with the new values.

Switching to async:false does not achive this.   For example, if I switch to async : false the release dialog  closes before the actual data has been updated (that is what Release() does) and the table is updated to show the effect of the update (that is what loadTable() does).

Comment: Ok.  So here is the code that fixed the issue.  I used ajaxStart() and ajaxStop().
    "Release": function () {
                $(this).ajaxStart(function () {
                        $("#release-in-progress").show(); 
                    });
                    $(this).ajaxStop(function () {
                        $("#release-in-progress").hide();
                        $(this).dialog("close");    // close this dialog
                    });
                    ReleaseSelectedAssays();   // release assays
                    loadAssayTable(true);